# segmentation fault (core dumped) while converting sensor_msgs to cvImage

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, realsense, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to subscribe the topic /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw  of realsense SR300.
Here is the node:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


void depthCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& depth_msg)
{
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr depth_ptr;
  try
  {
    cv::imshow("depth_view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(depth_msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_16UC1)->image);
    depth_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(depth_msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_16UC1); 
    //  cv::imshow("depth_view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(depth_msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1)->image);
    //  depth_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(depth_msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1); 

    cv::waitKey(1000);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to '32fc1'.", depth_msg->encoding.c_str());
      }

}
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        ros::init(argc,argv,"depth_distance");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
        image_transport::Subscriber sub1 = it.subscribe("/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw", 1, depthCallback);
        ros::spin();
        return 0;
     }
```

But when I ran the node , I met the fault:

```
rosrun cood_tran depth_distance                    
[1]    24671 segmentation fault (core dumped)  rosrun cood_tran depth_distance
```

I don't know why.
I ran it in gdb and I got this.

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/qiuyilin/catkin_ws/devel/lib/cood_tran/depth_distance __name:=depth_distance __log:=/home/qiuyilin/.ros/log/ee00c938-3e6d-11e9-a98e-0028f8fda2a0/depth_distance-1.log
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe3356700 (LWP 15807)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe2b55700 (LWP 15808)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe2354700 (LWP 15809)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe1b53700 (LWP 15814)]

Thread 2 "depth_distance" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffe3356700 (LWP 15807)]
0x00007ffff578d230 in ros::Time::now ()
    at /home/qiuyilin/librealsense-2.16.3/third-party/realsense-file/rosbag/rostime/src/time.cpp:261
261         return t;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317363/segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)-while-converting-sensor_msgs-to-cvimage/) by [七小丘人](https://answers.ros.org/users/33153/%E4%B8%83%E5%B0%8F%E4%B8%98%E4%BA%BA/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-04**:
It's most likely either a pointer dereference issue or some other simple cause, so I'd recommend running your node in GDB (or some other debugger if you prefer). Refer to [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) for info on how to do that.

**Comment by [七小丘人](https://answers.ros.org/users/33153/%E4%B8%83%E5%B0%8F%E4%B8%98%E4%BA%BA/) on 2019-03-04**:
but the program always goes into time.h and can't work when I use gdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that I had added realsense2_camera to cmakelist.txt and deleted it. Now it works. I think I have to understand how to decide dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [七小丘人](https://answers.ros.org/users/33153/%E4%B8%83%E5%B0%8F%E4%B8%98%E4%BA%BA/) with karma: 56 on 2019-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0